# Link for "serial voting" message

Tags: support, serial-voting

Why does the link for "Serial voting was reversed" message from the "Achievements" menu refer to the profile reputation page, instead of to the post where serial voting did happen?

[image]

For regular (not serial) voting the hyperlink refers to the corresponding post (answer or question).

Comment: What was the </html> tag for?

Comment: @Ollie for the end of the document :)