# How can I modify a bounty notice (e.g., fix a typo)?

Tags: support, bounties, spelling, bounty-remarks

I made a typo while offering a bounty on the question [Link for "serial voting" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285254/339911)

Is there a way to fix spelling errors in a bounty notice? Can site moderators do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Users and even moderators can't edit the bounty remark/notice after it's posted.

The only workaround that I know of, is to have a moderator refund the bounty, then you can start it again without a typo in the notice. However, since moderators usually have more urgent things to do, most likely such request will be declined, unless there's some really nasty typo.

Worth to mention, there is already a [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324104/editing-bounty-messages-is-it-finally-time-for-a-little-love-anti-doh-feat?noredirect=1&lq=1) asking to let us edit the message, without any progress on it, and [the original request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message) which was put into the developers backlog over three years ago, but they still didn't get to it as well.